# How do I call a reducer with a slightly-updated prop value?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-props

I have a button dropdown that fires a handler on click. The person's age is 21, but they clicked a selection on the dropdown to make themselves 30.

```
handleChange = (newAge: number) => {
  let updatedPerson = this.props.person
  updatedPerson.age = newAge
  this.props.updatePerson(updatedPerson);
};
```

The `this.props.updatePerson(updatedPerson)` is fine - but in my debugger I can see that setting `updatedPerson.age = newAge` doesn't actually update the value `age`. Do I have to put this in the reducer? Can I change the value of `updatedPerson` before I send it to the reducer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`props` in React are immutable - you can't modify them. `updatedPerson` variable still holds a reference to the props object.

In line:

```
updatedPerson.age = newAge;
```

the mutation happens. But since it's impossible - nothing is changed.

If you want to make it work, you could e.g. make a copy of `person` object.

```
let updatedPerson = { ...this.props.person };
```